# Filemaker import keeps un-matching fields

Tags: import, filemaker

I'm trying to get Filemaker to always match the same fields during an import from an Excel spreadsheet. I've tried the custom order option and the last order option, but each time it puts the Excel fields in order of appearance, and the Filemaker fields in some order of it's own.

Is there some way to get it to remember which fields match? It's a pain having to drag them around every single time.

I have access to the script that runs the Import process, if that's helpful, but don't want to touch it without knowing what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not matching on field names?

If your Excel file and FileMaker file *must* have different field names, you could import to a temporary table that matches on the Excel field names, then transfer from the temporary table into your permanent table.

More info on imports in general: http://www.filemaker.com/11help/html/import_export.16.20.html